# Why does the Internet stop working after upgrade to iOS 8

Tags: ipad, ios, internet

So I upgraded my friends 1st generation iPad from iOS 4 to iOS 8.1 on my MacBook Pro. Now he's complaining that the Internet sometimes doesn't work and when it does it works extremely poorly and he's blaming me that it's due to the iOS 8 upgrade. Was the iOS 4 version 1st generation iPad not supposed to have been upgraded to iOS 8.1?

Answer (score 2):

The 1st Gen iPad can only use up to iOS 5.1.1

so… either it's not a 1st gen or it's not running iOS 8

Comment: He claims it's a 1st generation. The iPad wasn't capable of being upgraded to a higher version on the actual iPad in settings, I had to do it on my MacBook Pro. It's currently running iOS 8 after my upgrade on it but he claims Internet is very slow,choppy and works poorly.

Comment: If it's a 1st gen, it would simply not be capable of receiving the update & iTunes wouldn't let you get far enough to break it. My answer, at present, still stands.

Comment: Lets say it's not 1st gen, then 2nd gen. I don't know however, it was an early gen iPad because I couldn't update the iPad from the actual iPad settings.

Comment: iOS 4 had no update method other than iTunes, that could be why. I'd honestly say [as a guess] it may have been just an OS too far. I dumped my iPhone 3GS for the same reasons [about the time the 5S came out].  One thing the early machines definitely suffer from is "memory too full" syndrome. If it's over half full [give or take], it **will** be slower - my 3GS was definitely faster once I dumped a whole load of songs from it, even though they should have had no influence on the OS itself.

Comment: @jet It most likely was an iPad 2. Did you check the version number before updating? It may have been iOS 5, since OTA updates came out in iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an first generation iPad it can't be updated to iOS 8.
Are you sure that you are running iOS 8? Go into Settings -> General -> About and check which version of iOS you currently have?
Have you checked so that the mobile networks isn't turned off in the iOS settings?
Which year is this iPad from? You can check which generation of iPad you have on the [Apple Support webpage](https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do). You will need to enter your serial number to check that. You can find your serial number in the About tab of iOS Settings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset iOS 8 Networking Settings
2. Disable a Wi-Fi System Service Setting

I hope they work for your friend.